# I wonder when the following 'call forwarding' is useful

Tags: javascript, wrapper, forwarding

Following code is from 'javascript.info'.

```
let wrapper = function () {
  return func.apply(this, arguments)
}
```

func is function here.

I assumed various situations, but failed to make a difference from using 'func' at it is.

I would appreciate it if you could give me an example of 'wrapper' being used in the field.

Comment: I guess, [debouncing / throttling](https://css-tricks.com/debouncing-throttling-explained-examples/) would be a comprehensive example

Comment: One example would be to add logging. It could also validate arguments. The pattern is so flexible there really isn't a comprehensive list of applications. From delegation to instrumentation to encapsulation, the wrapper pattern is incredibly useful.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of wrapper seems to be to protect its actions from being different from those of func, wherever it is called.